# WebApi viewmodel validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've been banging my head on trying to get ViewModels to validate with webapi 2.2

From the docs ..it should work:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

```
namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [ValidateModel]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Test(TestViewModel email)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return "ok";
            }

            return "not ok";
        }
    }
}
```

With or without the `ValidateModelAttribute` it just returns "ok" all the time...

The `ValidateModelAttribute` is registered in `WebApiConfig`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea whats going on here ? It's so much simpler to use `DataAnnotations` to prevalidate data.

Sample request:
`http://localhost:55788/api/values/Test?email=ss`

Returns: `ok`

Neither GET/POST changes anything

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` is already doing it for you

Comment: [HttpPost] try post. Instead of [HttpGet]

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh ModelState.IsValid is doing nothing, i'm passing in an invalid email, and it still returns ok

Comment: You will find email is null so its an invalid state so i have to check if parameter is not null && ModalState.IsValid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where simple MVC controllers seem to have no problem, in this web api example we apparently have to specify `[FromUri]`

This works just fine

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test([FromUri]TestViewModel email)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return "ok";
        }

        return "not ok";
    }
```

With this code i can now also implement jsonP behavior

Also the custom `ValidateModelAttribute` becomes obsolete, though it can still be useful if you want to throw an exception systematically when a ViewModel is invalid. I rather just handle it in code to be able to return custom error objects.